# I need to vectorise function creation vector

Tags: r

I need to create a vector, each value of which depends on the previous one. I did it with help of loop (for).

I need 9 elements: a1 = 0, a2 = 1.6, a[i+1] = a[i] + a[2] * k ^ (i - 1)

```
k <- 1.6
a <- c(0, 0.6)
for(i in seq(2, 8)) { a[i+1] = a[i] + a[2] * k ^ (i - 1) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
k <- 1.6
a <- c(0, 0.6)
i <- 2:8

c(a[1], cumsum(c(a[2], a[2] * k ^ (i - 1))))
#[1]  0.00  0.60  1.56  3.10  5.55  9.49 15.78 25.84 41.95
```

Comment: And what if I need b1 = 0.6, b[i+1]*k , (i = {1,...,8}) ?

Comment: @kurzanovart Sorry, it is not clear to me. What are you trying to do ?